# Vulnerable Facebook SDK Login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I recently added facebook sign-in functionallity to my website but i have a feeling that i have missed something crucial cause this does not feel secure and is very easy to fake the login.

As long as i know the facebook-id of a user i can just send it as a post variable directly to the php file and then get logged in with `$_SESSION['userid']`.

Is there any unique token or something that facebook returns that i can pass in my ajax query below and then compare in php against facebook?

#### login.php (html)

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='javascript:FBLogin();'>Login using facebook</a>
```

#### login.php (js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: '0123456789',
      version: 'v2.7' // or v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, ...
    });     
  });
});

function FBLogin()
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            getUserInfo(); //Get User Information.
        } else {
            alert('Authorization failed.');
        }
    },{scope: 'public_profile,email,user_location'});
}


function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,location{location{country}},picture', function(response) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: response,
            url: 'jquery/php-login_facebook.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg.error == 1) {
                    alert('Something went wrong');
                } else {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

#### php-login_facebook.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    require_once '../includes/db.php';

    extract($_POST); // extract post variables

    //check if facebook ID already exits
    $sql = DBi::$db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_id = %u LIMIT 1", quote_smart($id)));

    // Sign in user if facebook_id in tabl
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

        $row = mysqli_fetch_object($check_user);

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row->userid;
    }

    // More stuff after successful signin
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by **combining the javascript and php sdk** which also seems to be the "recommended" way to do it.

Pasting code below

**login.php (html)**

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='javascript:FBLogin();'>Login using facebook</a>
```

**login.php (js)**

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log('init');
    FB.init({
    appId      : '0123456789',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use any version
    }); 
};

function login_to_facebook() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('You are logged in &amp; cookie sets!');
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
    return false;
  };

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
Response.accessToken);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: response,
            url: '/callback/php-false-login_facebook.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log('ajax success');
                if(msg.error == 1) {
                    alert('Something Went Wrong!');
                } else {
                    console.log(msg);
                    // success
                }
            }          
        });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log('not authorized');
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in to facebook');
    }
}
```

**php-login_facebook.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();    

if(isset($_POST['authResponse']['accessToken']) && isset($_POST['authResponse']['signedRequest']))
{
    require_once '../libs/Facebook/autoload.php';
    require_once '../includes/db.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '0123456789',
      'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); die;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); die;
    }    

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
       $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

      try {

        $requestProfile = $fb->get("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,picture,locale");
        $profile = $requestProfile->getGraphNode()->asArray();
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); die;
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); die;
      }       
    } else {
        echo "Unauthorized access!"; die;
    } 

    $facebook_id = int_safe($profile['id']);

    //check if facebook ID already exits
    $sql = DBi::$db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_id = %u LIMIT 1", quote_smart($facebook_id)));

    // Sign in user if facebook_id in tabl
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($check_user);

    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row->userid;

    // More stuff after successful signin   
}
```

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript